# error when defining a std::shared_ptr with new operator

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying to define a `std::shared_ptr` with `new` operator in the following way:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
};

int main() {

  std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = new A();

  return 0;
}
```

but I obtained the following compile-time error:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:8:30: error: conversion from 'A*' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr' requested std::shared_ptr ptr = new A();

Anyway, the following definitely works:

```
      std::shared_ptr<A> ptr{new A()};
```

Does anyone of you know why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***tl;dr:* it's a consequence of the relevant constructor being `explicit`.**

When you initialise with `=`, you invoke copy-initialisation. C++ does not allow copy-initialisation of a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer, because it would be too easy to end up with an accidental implicit conversion from some arbitrary raw pointer into a `shared_ptr` that doesn't actually manage it.

This way, the only way you can "ensnare" a raw pointer into a `shared_ptr` is very deliberately and very explicitly (as you have correctly done in your second example). Now, only in this initialiser do you have to remember not to do so with a pointer you're already managing elsewhere.

Is there anything actually dangerous about the specific line `std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = new A()`? No. But what you're seeing is a consequence of various C++ rules working together in concert.

Answer (score 5):

You can imagine your statement also as a 2 liner like this.

```
A* a = new A();
std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = a;
```

While in this case this may be correct in more complicated code it can lead to potential pitfalls so copy initialization is not allowed to a raw pointer.

Imagine

```
A* a = new A();
//.....
std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = a;
//.....
std::shared_ptr<A> ptr2 = a; //second ptr holding a... UB
```

Here you would have 2 shared pointers holding the same object which causes trouble.

To avoid those "implicit" errors C++ is not allowing this kind of initialization.

While you can still to the same with constructors but it is more "verbose" and harder to accidentally assign pointers.

```
std::shared_ptr<A> ptr{ new A() };
```

This looks more like constructing a new object and may not result in an mis-assignment by accident.

Also the **preferred** way to create a shared pointer in modern is

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<A>();
```

Comment: No, that is not an assignment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah you are right. I rephrased that part.